# How can I see my previous winter-bash performances?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

Is there a way to see my previous performances with respect to winter-bash? May be something like leagues for winter-bash? I understand that hats are different each year, but at least it would be nice to see the number of hats collected.

Comment: The only way is to take screen shots. Winter Bash is a temporarily event, and all of the data will no longer be available as soon it's over (at least not publicly).

Comment: Yup, I understand that. That is why I tagged this as feature-request as well.

Comment: That's why I disagreed the [tag:feature-request], I think it's intentional, and should stay like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently your option is http://archive.org/web, and only if supposing you did have enough hats to be on the first pages or someone did capture the whole leaderboard.

E.g. the archived version of [network-wide leaderboard page 1](http://web.archive.org/web/20150101052540/http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) for the January 1, 2014 (not the last version as you can see).

Comment: Works for other pages of scores too!

Comment: @Canadian it does because they were archived (and archiving is done by humans, they aren't crawling sites). I've checked first three pages and yeah, they do work.

Comment: I got to page 10, anyways